# ¿Porque IntelXDK no me hace ejecutable/exe de mi webapp para windows?

Tags: windows, aplicación-web, intel-xdk

Tengo un juego que quiero convertir en webapp para windows. Cargo el proyecto en el servidor de IntelXDK y le doy a Start Builds como Web Application. 
Lo que me baja es un zip que al abrirlo me muestra los archivos que he subido al servidor de intelXDK, más una carpeta llamada xdk donde hay un archivo que se llama project-info.json También aparecen varios archivos en la misma carpeta donde estan mis archivos html. Unos son xml otros extensión xdk o xdek. 
Yo quiero ver un ejectuable, (exe) un único archivo, como cuando hacemos una app de android que nos genera un apk instalable. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: IntelXDK crea paquetes para mandar a la tienda (igual que los apk de android), no crea ejecutables. No le indiques Web APP sinó windows app.
Supongo que configurando el windows como desarrollador te permitiria instalar dichos paquetes sin pasar por la tienda.

Comment: En la pestaña develop, marca el icono con el logotipo de windows para que te permita hacer builds para windows. Deberás darte de alta como desarrollador para que te den un ID.

Comment: Gracias Arnau. Miraré si puedo hacerme un id de windows para poder hacer ejecutables. No me aparece como respuesta y no puedo cerrar la pregunta dándote la aprobación a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que para Android son APK, para windows 8/10 son .APPX (no exe) y están pensados para ser distribuidos desde la tienda de microsoft, para hacer un EXE, creo que deberías usar VB.NET, haciendo que habrá un navegador y cargando tu app, entonces si podría ser un EXE.
Hace años que no lo toco, pero debería ser trivial.